# In a multi NIC system, which system NIC IP is returned by InetAddress.getByName(hostname)

Tags: java, ip, hostname, inetaddress

I have a multi NIC system where NIC_1(public network), NIC_2(private network) are associated with IP_1, IP_2 respectively. Using the system's hostname  I tried to get the system IP using InetAddress.getByName(hostname) and I found that the InetAddress.getByName(hostname) returns the private IP IP_2 when I was expecting it to return the public IP IP_1. DNS is not configured and since I am running this code locally on the system, how does InetAddress.getByName(hostname) decide which IP to pick in a multi NIC system? 
I checked the Java API docs for InetAddress but I could not find any information on multi NIC scenario for that method. 
How did the method call pick private IP address and not the public IP address? With **DNS NOT configured**, how does the InetAddress.getByName(hostname) decide which system IP to return?

Answer (score 0):

you will get back the first matching entry from your /etc/hosts file